# next-i18next fail to load locales from public folder

Tags: next.js, internationalization, i18next, next-i18next

I migrated to next.js and started to use next-i18next. I would like to know, how to make next-i18next load locales from the public folder? It works only when I place the locales folder in the root directory not in public.

i18n.json ;

```
{
    "locales": ["en", "fr", "ar"],
    "defaultLocale": "en",
    "pages": {
      "*": ["common"]
    }
}
```

next.config.js ;

```
// next.config.js
const nextTranslate = require("next-translate");

module.exports = {
  ...nextTranslate(),
};
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Create `i18n.js` file root add this code inside:
const path = require('path');

```
module.exports = {
  i18n: {
    locales: ['en', 'ru', 'tm'],
    defaultLocale: 'en',
    localeDetection: false,
    localePath: path.resolve('./public/locales'),
  },
};
```

and add config `next.config.js` file this:

```
const { i18n } = require('./i18n');

const nextConfig = {
  reactStrictMode: true,
  i18n,
};

module.exports = nextConfig;
```

after every page add transalition code. example: index.file

```
import React, { useContext, useEffect } from 'react';
import { serverSideTranslations } from 'next-i18next/serverSideTranslations';
import { useTranslation } from 'next-i18next';
import Router from 'next/router';
import { Title } from '../components';
import i18n from '../i18n';

const Home = () => {
  const { t } = useTranslation('');

  useEffect(() => {
    if (!user) {
      Router.push('/login');
    }
  });
  return (
    <>
      <Title title={`${t('page.home')} | Trillo`} />
      <div className="min-h-screen">Home</div>
    </>
  );
};

export const getServerSideProps = async ({ locale }) => (
  { props: {
    ...(await serverSideTranslations(
      locale,
      ['common'],
      i18n,
    )),
  } }
);

export default Home;
```

After you create these files inside public folder like this. [see this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SdYMF.png) and [see this 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WHBV6.png)

Comment: Many thanks Alex! you are a lifesaver! Another issue apeared but luckily I solved it, I couldn't import the i18n from outside the src folder but I managed like this ; import i18n from '../../i18n';

Comment: Does the `i18n` config really have to be added to every call of `serverSideTranslations` ??

Comment: You should only add it if you don't use 'next-i18next.config.js' to name your configuration file. You should add it to `_app.{jsx|tsx}` HOC as second parameter.